# Group By DATE_FORMAT in SQL and Return Group of Unix Timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, unix, highcharts, timestamp

I'm trying to graph a data set returned from MySQL using the Highcharts framework. Below is the query and the formatting functions:

```
    function correlate_created_at_with_msg_vol($q, $time = NULL) {
      global $db; 
      date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

      $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $q);

      $query = "SELECT unix_timestamp(created_at) AS date,";
      $query .= " COUNT(tweet_id) AS count FROM `tweets`";
      $query .= " WHERE tweet_text LIKE '%{$q}%'" ;
      $query .= " GROUP BY created_at";
      $query .= " LIMIT 20";
      $tweets = mysqli_query($db, $query);
      confirm_query($tweets);
      return $tweets;
    }

    function format_data($q) {
      $msg_vol = correlate_created_at_with_msg_vol($q);

      while ($tweet = mysqli_fetch_array($msg_vol, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        # had ot modify correlate_created_at_with_msg_vol()
        # to no longer use unix timestamps
        $date = $tweet['date'] * 1000;
        $count = intval($tweet['count']);
        $formatted[] = array($date, $count);
      }
      return $formatted;
    }
```

The $date is being multiplied by 1000 (per Highchart's docs) to change the unix timestamp into milliseconds since EPOCH. However, this is breaking my `GROUP BY created_at` part of my query as they are no longer being grouped down to the minute. How can I adjust my query so that all records that occurred in a minute interval are still grouped while in unix timestamps?

Should I do the transformation after the SQL query using strtotime? I'm still learning but I am guessing that is going to be the solution; unfortunately, from what I understand, doing the process on the DB side is better for performance. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

I'd rather have the DB do the DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p') and return that with the row, but since I need a unix timestamp I can't find a way to do this.

I'm open to any and all suggestions/feedback/ideas/criticism. Thank you.

P.S.
I plan on dropping mysqli in favor of PDO... After I get this damn graph to work. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT floor(unix_timestamp(created_at)/60)*60 AS date,
       COUNT(tweet_id) AS count 
FROM `tweets`
WHERE tweet_text LIKE '%{$q}%'
GROUP BY date
```

This rounds every timestamp down to the beginning of the minute.

Comment: Barmar, you're a life saver! Thank you very much as that did exactly what I was hoping to accomplish.